# Is Podrick really such a good lover?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

During [*Game of Thrones*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/) S03E03 *Tyrion* donates his squire *Podrick* a stay with three whores as a reward for his services, especially during the battle of *Blackwater*. But when he returns he gives the money back to *Tyrion* saying that they wouldn't take it, much to the wonder of *Tyrion* and *Bronn*:

> **Bronn:** What did you tell them?
>   **Podrick:** I didn't tell them anything.
>   **Tyrion:** What did you do to them?
>   **Podrick:** Lots of things.
>   **Tyrion:** And they seemed to like these things?
>   **Podrick:** Yes, mylord.
>   **Bronn:** Of course they seemed to like it, they're paid to seem to like it.
>   **Tyrion:** Only they weren't paid.
>   **Bronn:** What you saying, those ladies enjoyed him so much they gave him the time for free?

But I wonder, **was there anything more serious behind this scene or is *Podrick* really just an exceptionally good lover?** While this question might seem trivial or speculative, I couldn't help but feel that this whole incident and conversation didn't contribute anything to the overall plot at all (especially in light of the IMHO rather minor role *Podrick* has in the story anyway). Yet, on the other hand *Podrick*'s loyality doesn't seem in question when judging by the rest of the story so far, so it isn't too likely that he made some sinister deal either. So **was this merely a little distraction or cheerful addition to *Podrick*'s character or was there actually more to it that ties this scene in with the bigger picture** (or maybe the source material is more elaborate)?

Comment: Good question, but what about Podrick just lying about it? From what I recall of that set of scenes, I got that impression.

Comment: @DustinDavis I didn't think about that, especially since that money *"was much more than [Tyrion] pays [him]"*, so he would have serious problems to get that together. Or do you mean he didn't actually sleep with the whores at all?

Comment: While I don't recall if he returned the money, if not, maybe he wanted to keep it. But I meant maybe he didn't sleep with the whores at all. The reason for lying I don't know, but speculate to boast about his "talents".

Comment: The implication is that he's extremely well endowed.

Comment: After watching that episode and reading the books i too have asked myself a couple of times what exactly Podrick did to those three whore and the thing is i've come to believe that maybe he really didn't do anything. What if it was just the other way around.

Comment: Or it might have been that the whores wanted to have a joke at Tyrion's expense, knowing that he would spend many sleepless nights wondering about it :))

Comment: The prostitutes are use to old ugly men, forcing themselves upon them.... Maybe a very nice change to have a young handsome shy gentle man to do with as they please???

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### There's probably no deeper meaning to it

Podrick is pretty much seen as the comedic sidekick. In both the books and the TV show he is the unfortunate recipient of plenty of witty quips (mostly by Tyrion), even the fandom have picked him up as a funny meme of sort ("I blame Pod" is very widespread among fans). Also, the incident with the whores never happened in the books. However, what did happen in both books and show was Pod showing his true mettle during the Battle of the Blackwater.

This leads me to believe that it's just poking fun at Pod while also giving the impression that there's more depth to Pod than a bungling squire.

Comment: Sets up several more seasons worth of jokes/references for Bronn and Tyrion to make whenever they see Pod, as we've seen since then.

Answer (score 25):

You might not have watched it yet, but in the season finale Podrick went to the courtyard to tell Tyrion there was a family meeting going on, and a couple of girls giggled and said, "Ooh, that’s him!", indicating that his reputation is spreading by word of mouth.  I think the in-universe answer is supposed to be yes, Podrick really is a good lover.

Comment: I have watched it, but didn't remember this.

Comment: I interpreted it the same way as you, but then again I can't help but wonder if the whole thing is part of Tyrion's "thank you". Have the women give the money back so Pod thinks he's a stud, and spread word about his abilities so others do as well.

Comment: @Dean Hmm, interesting. Maybe a bit too elaborate, but definitely an interesting theory.

Answer (score 16):

Though [user21855](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35090/23065)'s answer wasn't very specific, it is indeed true that there is that scene in the TV series. He really is a good lover with a no-larger-than-usual sized member. The girls couldn't explain exactly what it was that he did. There doesn't seem to be any particular reason for these scenes other than a sort of comic relief... thing.

The conversation between Ros and Varys takes place in 
Season 3, Episode 4 "**And Now His Watch Is Ended**". 
Roughly around the 12 minute mark - after Brandon's "dream" scene:

(possible spoilers ahead)

> (*Scene starts mid-conversation*)
>
> **Varys**: Is he very large?
>   **Ros**: No larger than usual, apparently.
>   **Varys**: And yet they said that he was -
>   **Ros**: (interrupts) - extraordinary. The most extraordinary man they've ever had.
>   **Ros**: And they've had a lot of men.
>   **Varys**: We're talking about the same Podrick; quiet boy, in lord Tyrion's service, seems a bit simple?
>   **Varys**: What did he do to them?
>   **Ros**: I don't know, my lord. The girls are usually quite descriptive.
>   **Varys**: So what did they say?
>   **Ros**: They said it was hard to describe...
>   **Varys**: Huh.
>   *Varys leans back for a moment, then pours a drink for Ros while he continues*
>   **Varys**: Prodigies appear... in the oddest of places.
>   **Varys**: And what did Littlefinger say about this loss of income?
>   **Ros**: He was too preoccupied to notice. He's leaving for the Eyrie soon.
>   **Ros**: I'm helping him prepare for his journey.
>   **Varys**: Ah yes... to pursue his enduring love of lady Arryn - and the title that comes with her.
>
> (*subject strays away from Podrick, master of the arcane art known as lovemaking*)

I've got your back, anon ;)

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, I made an account and answered some questions just so I could answer here. I am a little disappointed to see that no one here has referenced the first book's description of Podrick. In the book (I sadly don't have it in front of me; a friend has my copy, I believe it was in chapter 64), Podrick is described as having an abnormally large, thick tongue. I personally think that was involved in this situation.

Comment: Interesting addition!

Answer (score 1):

Littlefinger wants to spy on Tyrion.

Littlefinger tells his prostitutes to give Pod freebies any time he wants and to tell him that he is the best they have ever had. Pod visits the prostitutes and Littlefinger gets to hear what Pod tells the prostitutes.

It is not likely that Pod, a virgin, would be such a good lover that the prostitutes would be giving him a freebie, Littlefinger must have told them to do it. Littlefinger must have a good reason for doing it.

Comment: Interesting theory. But do you have anything to back that up a little?

Answer (score 1):

I thought perhaps THAT was really Tyrion's gift to Podrick...I mean it's nice to give Podrick a whore but as repayment for saving your life? Isn't the confidence boost of not only getting laid, but having the prostitutes like it so much that it us free, pretty much the penultimate gift to an awkward  (formally virgin) teenage boy? Tyrion is certainly clever enough to come up with a scheme like that.
That being said, the ensuing conversation with Varys and Ros, and the giggly girls seem to be supporting evidence that he really is that "good" (or big)
But again, wouldn't put it past Tyrion to be able to come up with such fabulous scheme that everyone truly believes it!

However I think that is probably as deep as it goes, I don't think it is foreshadowing anything larger, or indicative of something darker, just a little bit of character building/sex/humor for audience appeal.

Comment: Some thing that elaborate would get a mention,  a wink from Tyrion or something.

Answer (score 0):

Ros had a conversation with Varys explaining it, he's not particularly large it's just that the girls liked what he did.

Comment: I can't remember this scene. Can you add the specific season and episode number please.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point of the scene is that we are as confused, and surprised as Tyrion.  We're basically having the same reaction that they did.  We're desperately trying to figure out what the heck really happened, and having long discussions about it.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is just an example of lame 'for cable TV" writing. This is a sex and sword drama, so everyone who is able to has sex and kills or is killed. Podrick is the doofus, (isn't he also the last kings bastard?). I think this is a way to make fun of Podrick for being so out of it he doesn't even understand his own gifts. In this case his enourmous endowment. I doubt the writers are keen enough to simply make him "good in bed" or deepen the character of prostitutes so that they are bragging about a 'good' or attentive lover. That kind of bragging from a cut and paste prostitute usually adds up to "endowment". How funny, the nerd is hung -that's the joke. I would imagine that is all that was intended with that. It is possible that this was a foreshadowing of a plot point that has yet to be made or even a set up to a bigger joke that was dropped or, again, will happen later.

Comment: Pod is not a bastard.  He is of house Payne, as in the same House Payne as the King's Justice Ser Ilyn Payne (The guy who killed Eddard Stark)